# Calculate sum of array's prices included within range

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have the following task, write a method that takes a list of prices and sums them up, including only those that are greater than minPrice (inclusive) and less than maxPrice (inclusive), and returns the amount.

Only for loop can be used.

And I have a wrong result in return.

I presume that I have a mistake in if (price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice) counter++;

But I do not understand why.

```
    public int getPricesSum(int[] prices, int minPrice, int maxPrice) {
        
        if (prices.length == 0) return 0;
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            int price = prices[i];
            if (price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice) counter++;
        }
        
        int result [] = new int [counter];
        
        int newResult = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            newResult += prices[i];
        }
        
        return newResult;
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuadraticEquationSolver shop = new QuadraticEquationSolver();

        //Should be 144 - 20 + 50 + 40 + 34
        int[] prices = new int[] {10, 20, 50, 40, 34, 500};
        System.out.println(shop.getPricesSum(prices, 20, 50));
    }
  }
```

The result is 120.
I suppose it calculates only the first four indexes of the array.

Comment: Your code is counting the number of elements that are between min and max (let's call that `counter` and then sums up the first `counter` elements of the prices - regardless whether they are within the bounds or not.
Also you wrote "greater than minPrice and less than maxPrice" in your description, but in the code you are comparing with `>=` and `<=`, that means greater or equal to minPrice and less than or equal to maxPrice - what is the actual wanted behaviour?

Comment: Greater than minPrice and less than maxPrice (INCLUSIVE); 
My idea was to take all the elements that could pass if, and then declare another array with these elements and calculate them using the next loop.
Well, I'm just learning, thank you for your help! :) @cyberbrain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first bit where you were counting the number of prices within minPrice and maxPrice wasn't useful at all. Plus, declaring that second array sized with the number of prices contained within your range didn't help you in computing the sum of prices.

Right now, you just need to determine the sum of prices within your range. Counting is not part of your goal neither helping you with it. Before starting to code, always think about the steps you need to take to achieve your goal.

I think this is what you were attempting to do:

```
public int getPricesSum(int[] prices, int minPrice, int maxPrice) {
    int newResult = 0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        if (prices[i] >= minPrice && prices[i] <= maxPrice){
            newResult += prices[i];
        }
    }
    return newResult;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    QuadraticEquationSolver shop = new QuadraticEquationSolver();

    //Should be 144 - 20 + 50 + 40 + 34
    int[] prices = new int[] {10, 20, 50, 40, 34, 500};
    System.out.println(shop.getPricesSum(prices, 20, 50));
}
```

Comment: My idea was to take all the elements that could pass if, and then declare another array with these elements and calculate them using the next loop. Well, I'm just learning, much appreciate for your clarification! =) @Dan

Comment: @OrestDymarchuk I thought you were thinking something along those lines, but redeclaring another array with some of the same elements you already have in the first one is kind of a waste in terms of memory occupation and computation time. You can already achieve what you want with the first array you have, just play with  conditional statements. And don't worry about being new to programming. When I started I did much worse....

Answer (score 2):

Why do you increment a counter? You've just get the NUMBER of correct elements, but then you're iterating from the first (0) one. Instead, you can sum it up already in the first foor loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    int price = prices[i];
    if (price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice) newResult += price;
}
```

Comment: My idea was to take all the elements that could pass if, and then declare another array with these elements and calculate them using the next loop. Well, I'm just learning, much appreciate! =) @Begging

Answer (score 2):

```java
public int getPricesSum(int[] prices, int minPrice, int maxPrice) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int price : prices) {
        if (price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice) {
            sum += price;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```